# Microsoft.VsHub.HttpHost64.exe memory usage issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vshost32

I was happily debugging some C# code in Visual Studio 2015 when I started to notice that a VsHub related process (Microsoft.VsHub.HttpHost64.exe) was going bananas with memory consumption and slowing my whole system.

[image: Memory consumption while debugging]

and even after I close the application I was debugging and Visual Studio it still was consuming memory.

[image: Memory consumption after VS closed]

This keeps happening and makes debugging with Visual Studio a little bit frustrating... when this stuff is consuming more than twice the memory your own program is allocating.

Anyone having the same issue and solve it (without deleting/renaming the executable)?
Any thoughts?

Comment: I have same problem - did you find a solution?

Comment: I too have the same problem and it only occurs with some projects. Microsoft did report that they had fixed the issue in Update 3, but it is still happening for me. Let's hope VS2017 (which comes out tomorrow) solves this issue.

Comment: Nope, just waiting for 2017 :(